# FluentMigrator update columns where value is not null

Tags: c#, fluent-migrator

I want to update columns where values are not null. I can find values that are null in my database like that:

```
Update.Table("someTable").InSchema("schema")
                .Set(new { IsValid = false }).Where(new { IsValid = DBNull.Value });
```

but how to reverse `Where(new { IsValid = DBNull.Value });` condition to `is not null` ?

Comment: Doesn't `Where(new { IsValid != DBNull.Value });` work?

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras but how it would work? `Isvalid = DbNull.Value` is not comparison but assign. We are creating anonymous object here and `DbNull.Value` is property not bool or something